# Control files fetched from upstream when using nginx proxy cache

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache

we have a file sharing site in a local network and we trying to save links bandwidth usage to the max by caching static files in local nodes powered by nginx with caching enabled.

Everything works fine except when a user requests a file via nginx frontend, the whole file is transmitted to the nginx cache which is good sometimes, but what if the user canceled the download seconds later ! we will lose much bandwidth with large files.

**My questions**: 
is there a way to fetch part of the file from backend 
i.e get only 10% of the file, if a request with range larger than the fetched part occured then bring the rest of the file, or any similar implementation.

Comment: I don't know why the down vote, it a legit question, is it because no code or config with it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured the solution.

in case anyone faced the same you should use [ranger](https://github.com/caquino/ranger) which requires [openresty](http://openresty.org/) bundle and you can cache parts of the file until further parts requested.